# Data is not stored in table , no error but not travelling data on server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to stored data in table but when I store some special character like (' or back slash) there is no error from server but it's not stored in the table.

I actually try (`!@#$%^&*`) characters these all working fine but just (', black slash) is not working.

The code is below. What is the problem?

```
if(isset($_POST['timeline_final'])){   
        $body=$_POST['update_text'];
        $userid=$idd;
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post(body,posted_at,user_id,likes) VALUES ('$body',NOW(),$userid,0)");
}
```

Comment: don't see you are executing the query at all

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your query, it works fine but, your problem may be **$userid=$idd;** you did not define $idd. and one more thing use single quotes on values when you insert in database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['timeline_final'])){
$idd=0;
        $body=$_POST['update_text'];
        $userid=$idd;

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post(body,posted_at,user_id,likes) VALUES ('$body',NOW(),'$userid','0')");
}       
?>
```